# How to get the data of a row from when a user searches? Android SQLite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I've tried using this method of searching and returning the data from a table. But when I try to click the search button when I've already typed the name of that's present in the database, the app just crashes. Is there some other way to return the following information?

```
public String getName(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + nameSearch, null, null, null, null);
        if(c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String name = c.getString(1);
            return name;
        }
        return null;
    }

public String getProgramAndYearLvl(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + nameSearch, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String programAndYearLvlString = c.getString(2);
        return programAndYearLvlString;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getClassSecn(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + nameSearch, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String classSecnString = c.getString(3);
        return classSecnString;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getGrade(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "=" + nameSearch, null, null, null, null);
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String gradeString = c.getString(4);
        return gradeString;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Attach the logs and stacktrace as well

Answer (score 0):

Your method of accessing columnIndex is incorrect.
Do not assign columnIndexes by yourself instead use

> cursor_name.getColumnIndex("COLUMN_NAME")

Also, another problem is since it the query parameter is a string you must enclose the query in single quotes like following

```
Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='" + nameSearch + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Your final code will be as follows

```
public String getName(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='" + nameSearch + "'", null, null, null, null);
    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String name = c.getString(columnIndex);
        return name;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getProgramAndYearLvl(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='" + nameSearch + "'", null, null, null, null);
    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL);
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String programAndYearLvlString = c.getString(columnIndex);
        return programAndYearLvlString;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getClassSecn(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='" + nameSearch + "'", null, null, null, null);
    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CLASSANDSECN);    
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String classSecnString = c.getString(columnIndex);
        return classSecnString;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getGrade(String nameSearch) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PROGRAMANDYEARLVL, KEY_CLASSANDSECN, KEY_GRADE};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_NAME + "='" + nameSearch + "'", null, null, null, null);
    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GRADE);        
    if(c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String gradeString = c.getString(columnIndex);
        return gradeString;
    }
    return null;
}
```